# How do you send mail from the mac terminal when nothing works?

Tags: email, terminal

I have tried dozens of different ways including using mail, mail, and sendmail. I've tried installing smtp, mstmp, postfix, sendmail. I really don't know what's going on, so internet people, can you help me?

Edit: When I type this command:

```
mail name@gmail.com
```

I get this error:

```
 unknown: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 689: missing '=' after attribute name: "inet_interfaces loopback-only"
```

But if I try to edit that file in VIM it says its read only. In addition, I'm on a mac with a terminal running ZSH.

Comment: I think most of those assume you have a local mail server as a starting point for sending it on. I don't have a mac to hand to try, but some of these might work: [Can I set up system mail to use an external SMTP server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/can-i-set-up-system-mail-to-use-an-external-smtp-server) or [How to send an email from command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12387/how-to-send-an-email-from-command-line) (but see the note about configuration in the first answer, or use another one)

Comment: "But if I try to edit that file in VIM it says its read only." - you'd probably need to edit it as root.